# Powershell catch curl errors

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, curl, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple Powershell function to call a web api and get a response. How to find out if the web api call succeeded or failed. If failed how can i log only the failed exception message. I am using curl for windows.
Below is my Powershell script,

```js
function PowershellCore_CurlFunction()
{
    $curlResponse = curl -s  "$url"
    # How to check if web api call is succeeded or failed
    # How to log error if web api call throws exception
}
```

Comment: User try./catch to handle the error

Comment: Please note that `curl` is per default an _alias for Invoke-WebRequest_, and not cURL tool that's common in *nix environments.